# Variable scoping in php

Tags: php

I'm into an issue, while running alertError(), it seems to be fine and there is an access for $errors, but while running showErrors(), it tells me that the variable is underfined. "Undefined variable: errors in"

```
$errors = array();

function alertError($error){
    $errors[] = $error;
    echo $errors[count($errors)-1];
}

function showErrors(){
        echo "<html>
                <head>
                    <title>Error occurred!</title>
                </head>
                <body>";
                foreach($errors as $error){
                    echo $error."<br>";
                }
        echo "
                </body>
             </html>";
    die();
}
```

Why does alertError() seems to know that $errors is defined, and showErrors() is having trouble accessing him?

Comment: Read [variable scope in documentation](http://php.net/language.variables.scope). It explains everything.

Comment: This is the weird way to throw errors

Comment: PHP scopes don't inherit. You're in for hell if you're used to a saner programming language.

Answer (score 4):

Pass errors to `showErrors()`

```
function showErrors($errors){
   ...
}
```

You may need your code like this

```
$errors = alertError($error);
showErrors($errors);

function alertError($error){
    $errors[] = $error;
    echo $errors[count($errors)-1];
    return $errors;
}

function showErrors($errors){
        echo "<html>
                <head>
                    <title>Error occurred!</title>
                </head>
                <body>";
                foreach($errors as $error){
                    echo $error."<br>";
                }
        echo "
                </body>
             </html>";
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When function 'alertError()' runs it doesn't know anything about global variable $errors. It create new variable $errors every time.
So it works correctly but not so as you want. In showErrors this variable is not declared so you get a notice.
You can use statement **global $errors** in each function but it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

add this line at the first line of showErrors()

```
global $errors;
```

this will give u access to the global $errors you declared above the functions

**Update**

As mantioned buy Mr. Alien and  Neil Neyman in the comments - its a bed practice..
If you are going to program some php for more complex system - you should understand the OOP concept as shown in their links and comments.

**Good Luck !**

Comment: Yuks no... don't suggest using globals

Comment: why not? inside the function not in the declaration of the variable

Comment: [Why not](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+not+use+global&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)?

Comment: @asaf-nevo considered  bad practice. Better to either use a function parameter or  if it needs to maintain state between all funcs have both functions inside a class that access the variable like $this->errors

Comment: One exception might be a file of global vars to use as constants.  But defines are probably better for that.

Comment: ok but when you see that the user who asked the question is not a php programmer, but probably just trying to use php for a small need, to learn the whole concept of OOP might be a bit too complicated for him... i will add that its a bad practice though..

Comment: Actually, you need to add `global $errors` to ALL functions that access this variable. And I repeat: Using global variables is a bad thing - even the tiniest things will go wrong if not done properly, like your "quick fix".